# Pass custom/dynamic product information during add to cart process

Tags: expresso-store

I need to pass a custom, and dynamic field through from the page that has the Add to Cart button on it, all the way through checkout. How would I go about doing this?

Basically, I have some Add to Cart buttons that add a specific "product" from the Store Products channel and the Product they add, depends on the entry from a secondary channel so I need to pass the entry_id from that secondary channel all the way through.

Hopefully this makes sense and hopefully it's a quick answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You want to take a look at custom product modifiers:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#inputcustom_modifier_name

This will let you pass any text along with the product through to the checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian. I saw that, the issue is that I don't want a text input, I need it to be a hidden value because I am just using the data to populate backend product/order data.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using different types of inputs. Text, hidden, checkbox, radio - anything will work. You still need to specify it in the template though so that Store knows about the input parameter.